# How to be Recommended to be a Sitecore MVP?

Tags: community, mvp

Currently I do not personally know any Sitecore MVP's or employees to recommend me for this honor.  I feel like I've given back to the community (although I'm looking to expand this even further in 2017).  There's probably a lot of developers in the same boat as me.

**How might someone like me get recommended for consideration towards becoming a Sitecore MVP?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Make sure you have enough quality content online and use social channels to share your thoughts:

- on Twitter use #Sitecore https://twitter.com/search?q=%23sitecore
- on LinkedIn join the appropriate groups
  https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/g?type=groups&keywords=sitecore
- on Facebook use the Sitecore group https://www.facebook.com/groups/6932529533/
- you can request your blog to be added to the [Blog Feed](http://feeds.sitecore.net/)
  https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/4183

Also offline contribution matters, so participate conferences, user groups and other events. These events can also help you meet Sitecore employees or MVPs.

Recommendation is not everything, but it is always good that someone feels that your contribution is worthwhile, so make sure to have at least one!

**Update:** As of Nov 2018 the recommendation can be sent after logging in to the MVP Application area for current MVPs. Sitecore employees have an internal form to submit recommendations.

Comment: The recommendation page leads to a 404.

Comment: @jammykam thanks for the info. corrected it.

Comment: Where and how to request my blog to be added to the feed?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya you can request it here: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/4183

Comment: I requested my blog to be added there. Not sure if it ever made it or not. :)  Just to add one more spot to post. Reddit also has a Sitecore chat. https://www.reddit.com/r/sitecore/

Answer (score 30):

## The focus on recommendations

First of all; *don't worry too much about recommendations*. They matter, but they are not the do-all end-all defining thing that makes you an MVP or not. While I can't speak for all of the internal processes that take place in Sitecore when MVPs are evaluated, I feel fairly confident the recommendation system helps "tip the scale" for candidates that end up in a bit of a grey zone. You cannot rely on recommendations alone to make it through.

## Focus on your community work

If you feel you've put in the time and you should be considered for nomination; by all means let Sitecore know about it. And keep focusing on your community work. Don't show up after being almost invisible for a year, in November and start Tweeting like a maniac ;-)

## How do I nominate myself?

The application process changed for MVP 2019, and you can no longer nominate yourself. You must get at least one recommendation from an existing MVP or Sitecore employee. You will, receive an email with a link to apply once they have recommended you.

You can read more about the application process [in this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8678/135).

## How can I introduce myself to the community?

The Sitecore social sphere is growing ever faster, and while Sitecore does keep track of what goes on in the community - it is unlikely they will know everything you've been up to during the year. Until you tell them :-)

For this reason there is a new Forum on [Sitecore Community](https://community.sitecore.net/) where you can [Introduce Yourself](https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/52/t/11257). Please use this as an opportunity raise awareness of your Community Contribution.

Answer (score 9):

The request to become an MVP is organic. If you participate in the community, blog on Sitecore, come to the user groups (maybe do a talk or two). Then you will meet the other MVP's or employees who can support you in your endeavor.

The community is open, friendly and welcoming. Reach out to a few of the MVPs on Twitter and see if they can help you. But be prepared that your involvement in the community should be apparent.

Best

Answer (score 3):

You have been getting some great advice. I will completely agree that the recommendations are not the end all, be all. I have several friends that are MVPs. Their recommendation to me has been to not focus on the status but to focus on strong deliverables, speaking engagements and community.

I do have a few more words of encouragement for you.

I noticed that the closest Sitecore User Group to you is Orlando. I encourage you to start a local Sitecore User Group in Palm Beach. To start a User Group, contact Sitecore, they will get you on your way. If you need some help with it, reach out to me. I can get you on your way with it. I can also give you some help with general User Group stuff as well.

The other thing would be is to speak at local user groups, even if they are not Sitecore. User Groups are always looking for speakers. You can be creative with how you integrate Sitecore with a non-Sitecore group. For example, a did a talk on Full Stack development, and discussed Full Stack development and how it affects Sitecore.

Comment: I'm currently involved in a Sitecore South Florida User Group, haven't presented yet, but I hope to soon.  One thing I would like to explore is Virtual User Groups, is there a way to get involved in something like that?

Comment: Definitely! Hedgehog hosts a Virtual User Group. You can check it out at http://sitecoreug.org/usergroups/sitecore-users-virtual-group/. You can also find other user groups at http://sitecoreug.org.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are correct above and i am probably replying late. 
You don't need really need to know an existing MVP face to face, a LinkedIn connection or twitter will do for you. The 'should have' is you put all answers to nomination questions in a word file and share that file to existing MVPs on social media. The must have is the contribution to Sitecore community made in this year and visible passion for it.

If you have above things mentioned i don't think any right thinking MVP will deny you right of recommendation, please send me your credentials in word file and i will recommend based on that.