# What information is needed for the Sitecore MVP application?

Tags: community, mvp

I have done so much for the community and I have been recommended by an existing MVP.

What information shall I provide about myself during the application?

Comment: Related: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/how-to-become-a-sitecore-mvp

Comment: Related: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/what-should-i-expect-in-the-mvp-nomination-or-first-time-application-process

Comment: As a Sales Rep, would you require blog posts for the Ambassador MVP?

Comment: Radu, none of the links to your online presence are required for anyone. Since this is not a certification Sitecore is interested in what you do and not what you don't.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

During the application you will be asked:

- personal information

  - official name
  - personal email address
  - country/state where you live
  - name of your Mentor(s) if any
- links to your online presence

  - Blog URL
  - LinkedIn profile
  - Sitecore Community profile
  - Stack Exchange profile
  - GitHub
  - Twitter
- your motivation: why do you want to become an MVP?
- your objectives for the next year
- summary of your online and offline activities

  - list the Sitecore User Groups you Presented and attended
  - list any Videos or other media you produced to help the Sitecore community
- name of the company you are working for

You can prepare this before the MVP application opens and you will need just copy into the form when it is available.

Comment: i have submitted the MVP application today.i got confirmation also.Now should another MVP recommend(not nominate) after the application has been submitted?

Comment: This is not mandatory, but if you feel that it can support your application then MVPs can recommend you. On the other hand it is more important what you have in the application than having more recommendations.